# How to prevent PhpStorm scrolling up in code?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

If my cursor is in the middle of the screen and I open the terminal (ALT+ENTER) then it pushes the code|cursor up to the top.

This is so annoying. And I have no idea how to search for that in the settings.

Any idea?

I have added video: https://youtu.be/nOmGUmHeowg

I have tested with versions 2017, 2018, 2020: https://youtu.be/L7E0QYa7JR8

### Update

A **temporary fix** is to pull the tool window (for example the terminal) all the way to the top. If you now open the tool window the editor is completely covered and no more affected.

Here is a link to bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-36031

Comment: Try making some short screencast/video that would illustrate the issue. Right now I do not see how the steps from your description can do that (it does not do it here; I must be doing something differently or not noticing it).

Comment: @LazyOne added video to question.

Comment: I see now. For me it's expected and normal behaviour that works for ANY toolwindow, not just built-in Terminal: to keep current editor line in focus (I remember seeing some old debugger related tickets: to keep the line with breakpoint visible when debugger is triggered).

Comment: In any case: [the best I could find](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=editor%20scroll%20toolwindow) is this old ticket that is related but not exactly your case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-36031 If you get to response from JetBrains devs/support team members here in 1-2 days, feel free to submit a ticket to the Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: PhpStorm support reporting in. I am pretty sure it's been like that long before 2020.2 if not always, so there's no point in regretting about updating. The issue @LazyOne found seems to be accurate, so please vote for it

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. I had the 17th version. Never had this code moving crap. Tried the virtual space - did not solve the problem. Will open a ticket there. Thanks again.

Comment: Im going crazy ... now they are down -.- `It's not just you! youtrack.jetbrains.com is down.`.  `The server is temporarily overloaded, please try again later.`
Great!

Comment: Update: tested older versions. 2017 ok, 2018 bug appears, 2020 still bugged.

Comment: Month passing by and not even a reply on the issue -.-
(And the bug exists in 2021 version too -.-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since (at least) PhpStorm 2022.2.3

*(Did not check previous versions.)*

you can set

**terminal** settings > **view mode** > **undock**

[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrZG.png)

And then the weird scrolling is gone (finally).